# How do I filter a doubly linked list?

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

```
struct Node 
{
    int tutorID;
    string tutorName;
    int day_join;
    int month_join;
    int year_join;
    int day_ter;
    int month_ter;
    int year_ter;
    int hourly_pay_rate;
    int phone;
    string address;
    int centerCode;
    string centerName;
    int subjectCode;
    string subjectName;
    int rating;
    struct Node* prev;
    struct Node* next;
};

cout << "Enter Rating:" << endl;
        cin >> rating;
        while (current != NULL)
        {
            if (current->rating == rating) 
            {
                cout << "Tutor ID:" << current->tutorID << endl;
                cout << "Tutor Name:" << current->tutorName << endl;
                cout << "Date Joined:" << current->day_join << "/" << current->month_join << "/" << current->year_join << endl;
                cout << "Date Terminated:" << current->day_ter << "/" << current->month_ter << "/" << current->year_ter << endl;
                cout << "Hourly Pay Rate:" << current->hourly_pay_rate << endl;
                cout << "Phone:" << current->phone << endl;
                cout << "Address:" << current->address << endl;
                cout << "Center Code:" << current->centerCode << endl;
                cout << "Center Name:" << current->centerName << endl;
                cout << "Subject Code:" << current->subjectCode << endl;
                cout << "Subject Name:" << current->subjectName << endl;
                cout << "Rating:" << current->rating << endl;
                current = current->next;
                flag = 1; /*tutor details found*/
                break;
            }
            current = current->next; /*move to one node to another*/

        }
        if (flag == 0) /*if still no match found*/
            cout << "Not found" << endl;
```

I'm trying to search tutors based on ratings. Since ratings can be duplicated, searching through it will return multiple tutors. But I only got 1 tutor instead. How do I get multiple tutors based on rating?

Comment: Don't break. Instead copy the results to a `std::vector<Node>`.

Comment: If you just want to output the data instead of storing it in a vector to process later, then just output like you're doing. The advice about not breaking holds.

Comment: Recommendation: Separate the linked list from the data it contains. It's easier debug the list and the logic that supports and acts on the data separately and makes it easier reuse the list later with different data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `break;` from your loop.